# How to import 2D/3D CAD drawing into Blender and how to convert wireframes to faces?

Tags: modeling, import, faces, wireframe

I'm trying to import CAD drawings into Blender. I have read and looked at some tutorials about this, but it's not working! I can use DraftSight to transform a .dwg file to .svg, but to transform a .dwg to .dxf does not work, despite that I try all kinds .dxf versions!

I have also tested some other software like IrfanView, but to be able to handle .dwg files you have to buy an extra plugin and I have also looked at Teigha which is now called ODA File Converter and it's not free anymore.

What other options are there to handle cad drawings in Blender? Are there any other better file formats? I really need to solve this because I have a client that expect me to be able to handle CAD drawings in Blender.

Is it only possible to import 2D CAD files or is it also possible to import 3D CAD files and perhaps also view them as solid object and not just view them as wireframes?

When a CAD drawing is imported into Blender, what is the best working method to transform the wireframes into faces? Should I just a use the wireframes in the background and draw new faces with the snap tool or can I convert the wireframes to faces in some other way?

Preciate some tips and guidance about this subject. Thanks!

Comment: I regularly use DrafSight to convert DWGs into DXF and import them in Blender without issues. Why is that not an option for you?

Comment: Did you ever get this answered? By chance did you develop a working protocol for this? If you did would you please share it? I need to work with CAD files and although I have had some limited success with .STL my geometry is triangular etc. messy to work. and comes with internal geometry I don't need. I need to ask machinery manufacturers to provide me their machines in a 3d format I can use in Blender and I have no clear understanding what I should be asking them for. Help greatly appreciated.